# Custom plugin for handsontable with callback

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have a specific requirement for remove row in handsontable grid. I want to use RemoveRow plugin. but I needed a callback function after removing the row, Is there are any way to do this. I am open to do necessary changes in plugin (which i feel is required ).

I am not very comfortable with context menu options. ( I also considered the option of complete custom plugin, however I feel RemoveRow plugin easily done all the things (UI stuff), I want except a callback )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem by altering the plugin. check the [paste bin url](http://pastebin.com/NMye1YV3).